# Advice on Pyramid views exception handling

Tags: python, exception, web-applications, pyramid

There are three situations when I need to handle exceptions.

When data validation raised exception

When library/module functions raised exceptions (e.g. database connection abort)

When business logic raises exception such as 500, 503, 401, 403 and 404

```
def library_func():
    try:
        ...
    except HTTPException:
        raise TwitterServiceException("Twitter is down!")

@view_config(route_name="home", renderer="json")
@validator
@authorization
def home_view(request):
        try:
            tweets = library_func()
            return {"tweets": tweets}
        except TwitterServiceException as e:
            LOG.critical(e.msg)
            raise ParnterServcieError(e.msg)  # this is probably a 503 error

def validator(args):
    # I will show the high level of this decorator
    try:
         decode input as JSON
         verify data format
    except ValueError as err:
        error = {'error': "Missing required parameters."}
    except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
        error = {'error': "Failed to decode the incoming JSON payload."}
    if error is not None:
        return HTTPBadRequest(body=json.dumps(error),
                              content_type='application/json')

def authorization(args):
    # very similar to validator except it performs authorization and if failed
    # 401 is raised with some helpful message.
```

The doc suggests [Custom Exception Views](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#custom-exception-views). In my PoC above, I will tie `ParnterServcieError` as one. I can even generalize `HTTPBadRequest` and all `praymid.httpexceptions` using custom exception so that I no longer need to repeat `json.dumps` and `content_type`. I can set a boilerplate `error` body before I return `request.response` object.

Idea:

```
@view_config(context=ParnterServcieError)
def 503_service_error_view(e, request):
    request.response.status = 503
    request.response.json_body = {"error": e.msg}
    return request.response
```

I can generalize one for all uncaught, unspecified exceptions (which results in 500 Internal Server Error) called `500_internal_server_error_view`.

Does this seem sane and clean to people? Is my way of handling high and low level of exceptions proper and Pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

I applied this strategy to ToDoPyramid and could encapsulate error handling in a single custom exception view that was repeated multiple times in the application before. Until you could even improve it, you got a great idea. Pyramid rocks.

References

- [Catching database connection error in ToDoPyramid](https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L31)